# NSoperation and key value observing

Tags: objective-c, iphone, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I am creating a MyOperation object (inherited from NSOperation) and add to a NSOperationQueue. Then I am doing KVO on MyOperation.
I am using this method

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context;
```

to get a value from MyOperation if it is finished. In this method I am using a convenience method from an other class to get some other data.

Maybe here synchronization problems in the observeValue... method?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

NSOperation uses KVO intrinsically in it's operation; having to implement isFinished and isExecuted as part of the processing, for example are 100% KVO and are part of an operation's required contract with a client/queue. So advising that these should be avoided is inaccurate; NSOperation uses KVO itself so adopting dannywartnaby's premise would indicate that the implementation of NSOperation is in itself flawed, which is definitely not the case.

Admittedly the developer must take care to use KVO properly, although i would argue that subclassing NSOperation is a non-trivial task probably left for the more experienced Objective-C programmer. Notifications, one could argue, are too coarse grained for the kind of work undertaken by an operation, although not always, i think we must be careful when advising on practices to ensure that the wrong message isnt passed as best practice. Danny, would you care to elaborate on why using KVO is not advised when using NSOperation or threads? many examples of NSOperation implementation use KVO...

Comment: NSOpertation using KVO in it's impl is a moot point; I'm not saying KVO is bad, I'm saying a notification is a better choice. Other classes using KVO doesn't suddenly make all uses of KVO valid. Using KVO for this binds you exclusively to operations, to knowing keypaths, to becoming observers which in turn couple your two classes together. A notification on other hand is simple; post it in your operation, give it the data, and something else in the app ...

Comment: I suggest you read my comment again, i never said or implied that it "makes all uses of KVO valid" i just pointed out that you saying it "isn't wise" to use KVO is very misleading. Think of any occasion when you would use KVO as opposed to Notifications; Notifications are coarse grained and broadcast, KVO implies a coupling between two objects.Think of the concept of an operation, its an atomic piece of work, something creates it, and something will probably need to monitor what its doing and when its complete. if the app needs to know whats happening Notify, if the client only does, KVO

Answer (score -3):

I don't know your use-case, but using KVO for threads/operations isn't wise.

You could instead have your Operation object post a notification once it's complete. Or alternatively define a delegate protocol and give your Operation a delegate... you can then define some kind of 'myOperationComplete:' method which is invoked by your Operation against the delegate it was given, using performSelectorOnMainThread.

Comment: Everything is working well with KVO. I just want the issues if there are any. You said there are some issues. Can you point it out which are those?

Comment: The operation may be cancelled before the "main" is called. So posting a notification involves some extra work in some cases.