# Marking custom subclass of NSOperation as terminated?

Tags: cocoa, key-value-observing, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I've created a custom subclass of NSOperation and I've overwritten the `main` method.

```
@interface WGTask : NSOperation
@property(readonly) BOOL isExecuting,isFinished;
@end


@implementation WGTask
@synthesize isExecuting,isFinished;
- (void)start {
    ...
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
    isFinished=YES;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
    ...
}
@end
```

But this code raises an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. Removing `[self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"]` and `[self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"]` solves the problem, but even if the `isFinished` value is correctly updated, the NSOperationQueue doesn't remove the operation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My fault.  Before calling `[self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"]` I was calling a delegate method of my custom subclass in which I was releasing the task itself. That's why I got the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error, because `self` didn't exist anymore.

Comment: had to re-read this a few times to get it (this also helped http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291834/asihttprequest-dealloc-and-exc-bad-access-problem) but i ended up finding that my view was "autoreleased" and thats why i was getting my exc_bad_access.

Answer (score 1):

Don't create isExecuting et al as a property

From the docs:

If you are implementing a concurrent operation, you should override this method to return the execution state of your operation. If you do override it, be sure to generate KVO notifications for the isExecuting key path whenever the execution state of your operation object changes. For more information about manually generating KVO notifications, see Key-Value Observing Programming Guide.

Really, you probably want to use the cancel semantics of an NSOperation

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html

You may also wish to read

[NSoperation and key value observing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608355/nsoperation-and-key-value-observing)

and (if you are using these flags for dependency management)

[NSOperation KVO problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202491/nsoperation-kvo-problem)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but removing all properties and overwriting the `- (BOOL)isExecuting` and `- (BOOL)isFinished` doesn't seem to work. I still get the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. Maybe I'm forgetting something. Do I have to implement some other methods to get the KVO working? The main issue is that the operation queue doesn't get notified when the operation terminates.

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7805702/how-to-check-if-nsoperationqueue-is-finished-and-if-any-operation-failed