# How to check if NSOperationQueue is finished and if any operation failed?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I'm trying to parse some XML files in the background so that the UI doesn't freeze. I have to check two things:

- NSOperationQueue is finished?
- NSOperation - parsing did fail?

I have a class that subclasses NSOperation and a delegate is called if the parsing failed. Operations in the queue are limited to one simultaneously.

My problem is that I can't rely on the fact that the failed message is executed before I get the queue did finish message. Sometimes I don't get a failed message before I get the finished message. Then, for example, I have this order:

Operation 1 Successful
Operation 2 Successful
OperationQueue finished
Operation 3 Failed

All messages are sent to the main thread. After I get the finished message I want to proceed  in my code, but only if all operations were successful. How can I handle the problem that the delegate message is called after my queue is finished.

This are some parts of my code:

```
//XMLOperation.m
- (void)main {    
    NSLog(@"Operation started");

    if ([self parseXML]) {
            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(finishedXMLParsing) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
        } else {
            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(failedXMLParsing) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"Operation finished");
}


//StartController.m
[self.xmlParseQueue addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"operations" options:0 context:NULL];

...

- (void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object 
                         change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if (object == self.xmlParseQueue && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"operations"]) {
        if ([self.xmlParseQueue.operations count] == 0) {
            // Do something here when your queue has completed
            NSLog(@"queue has completed");
        }
    }
    else {
        [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object 
                               change:change context:context];
    }
}
```

Comment: as of Jan 2017, the Apple doc mentions that you can access "operationCount"  .  Just check this when needed.  https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsoperationqueue?language=objc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably happens because your KVO notification for the `operations` property of the queue is not necessarily delivered on the main thread while your finished/failed notifications are.

You should ensure that the completion notification is performed on the main thread as well, so  that the order of your notifications is defined.

Comment: The same way you do it in the `main` method of your operation, by performing the "something" you do when the queue has completed on the main thread.

Comment: I've verified the KVO solution and it failed, when the last operation will be executed but not yet, the operation queue's operations array has remove it, so it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Resume this question and paste my code solution here.

```
void RunInMainThread(void (^block)(void))
{
    if (!block) {
        return;
    }

    if ([NSThread isMainThread]) {
        block();
    } else {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), block);
    }
}

@interface MyOperationQueue : NSOperationQueue

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSUInteger totalCount;
@property (nonatomic, copy) dispatch_block_t allOperationCompletionBlock;

@end

@implementation MyOperationQueue

- (void)addOperation:(NSOperation *)op
{
    [super addOperation:op];
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

    self.totalCount++;
    DDLogVerbose(@"Added a operation, total: %ld operation(s).", self.totalCount);

    op.completionBlock = ^ {
        weakSelf.totalCount--;
        DDLogVerbose(@"Finished a operation, left: %ld operation(s).", weakSelf.totalCount);

        if (weakSelf.totalCount == 0) {
            if (weakSelf.allOperationCompletionBlock) {
                RunInMainThread(weakSelf.allOperationCompletionBlock);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

@end